# Polynomial Derivative handling exponent of 0

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomials, derivative, exponent

I have a method that takes in a polynomial `Linked List` as a parameter and returns a new list, which is the derivative of the polynomial.

Here's what I have:

```
private PolyNode derivative(PolyNode poly) {
    PolyNode temp = new PolyNode(0, 0);
    PolyNode res = temp;

    // While both Lists are not empty
    while (poly != null) {
        if (poly.power > 0) {
            temp.next = new PolyNode(poly.coef * poly.power, poly.power - 1);
            temp = temp.next;
            poly = poly.next;
        }
    }
    // Return new List, the result polynomial
    return res.next;
}
```

When I run the program, it never finishes compiling and partially returns the list; only the terms that have a higher power than 0.
I tried adding

```
if (poly.power == 0) {
    temp.next = new PolyNode(0,0);
    temp = temp.next;
    poly = poly.next;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The compiler seems to get stuck and never finishes compiling. It partially returns the list (only returns terms which have a higher power than 0). I guess it isn't technically an error, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely to your `while` loop:

```
// While both Lists are not empty
while (poly != null) {
    if (poly.power > 0) {
        temp.next = new PolyNode(poly.coef * poly.power, poly.power - 1);
        temp = temp.next;
        poly = poly.next;
    }
}
```

`poly` won't change unless its `power` is greater than zero. So when a `poly` with 0 `power` is found, your loop gets stuck.

Change it to:

```
while (poly != null) {
    if (poly.power > 0) {
        temp.next = new PolyNode(poly.coef * poly.power, poly.power - 1);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    poly = poly.next;
}
```

This way you effectively throw out any constant (`power == 0`), while still looping over `poly` list.